# Nestjs TypeError: applicationConfig.getVersioning is not a function

Tags: swagger, nestjs

```
I have reinstalled @nestjs/swagger and swagger-ui-express. All my dependencies are up to date. But I get this error:

applicationConfig.getVersioning is not a function at SwaggerExplorer.exploreRoutePathAndMethod

I have updated metadata tags in tsconfig.ts file as well. After debugging, I can find that the main issue is at line where createDocument function is called from Swagger Module class. Every code line before that works fine.

On console logging, I even could extract the values of config-correctly. However, once the createDocument method is called, the API comes to a crashing halt with the above stated error.
```

```
/home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-explorer.js:125
        const controllerVersion = this.getVersionMetadata(metatype, applicationConfig.getVersioning());
                                                                                      ^
TypeError: applicationConfig.getVersioning is not a function
    at SwaggerExplorer.exploreRoutePathAndMethod (/home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-explorer.js:125:87)
    at /home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-explorer.js:72:45
    at Array.reduce ()
    at /home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-explorer.js:71:99
    at /home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13469:38
    at /home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4967:15
    at baseForOwn (/home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3032:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13468:7)
    at MapIterator.iteratee (/home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-explorer.js:71:45)
    at MapIterator.next (/home/prasanna/my_project/TapisProject/API/API/node_modules/iterare/src/map.ts:9:39)
```

Comment: you need to upgrade `@nestjs/core` as well

Comment: Thakd you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to upgrade @nestjs/core as well –